# How to get the data type of db2 variables in php?

Tags: php, sql, db2

From a PHP code,I am trying to insert a new row to a DB2 table where I have the column names but not the corresponding data types.

`Insert into <table_name> (column1,column2,column3,.....) values ('value1','value2','value3',....)`

So, if any column is of date or timestamp data type, the single quotes around `'value'` makes db2_exec function to  throw an error:

`Warning: db2_exec(): Statement Execute Failed in C:\Program Files (x86)\insight_db.php on line 68
[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/NT64] SQL0180N The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect. SQLSTATE=22007 SQLCODE=-180`

to avoid placing `''` around such values, I need to get the data type of each column of the table and thereby checking a condition whether to place the quotes or not.

Comment: DB2 isn't complaining about the quotes.  It's complaining about the format of the date or timestamp.  'YYYY-MM-DD' should be fine.  What are you using?

Comment: In my case I am getting the values dynamically. The values can be empty as well.If I insert nothing to a date variable in the cotrol center, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query the catalog view `SYSCAT.COLUMNS` to obtain the information:

```
select
  colname, typename
from 
  syscat.columns
where
  tabschema = 'YOURSCHEMA' and
  tabname = 'YOURTABLE'
```

However, your approach is not going to work, because datetime literals *must* be enclosed in single quotes, and removing them will render your `insert` statement invalid. To avoid the SQL0180N error you can supply datetime values in the ISO format, e.g. `YYYY-MM-DD-HH.MM.SS` for `TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the datatype of the columns you can try this :

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM sometable");
if ($result) 
{
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {
         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
         {
             print_r($row['Field']);
             print_r($row['Type']);
         }
    }
}
```

then this will print the Field Name and Data Type of the field.

I hope you will find it little helpful.

Comment: But can you give me any solution that could work for IBM  DB2??

Comment: I think this might work :

DESCRIBE TABLE schema.TABLE_NAME
The command will output the following information for each column.

Column Name
Type Schema
Type Name
Length
Scale(precision)
Nulls(is nullable)

Comment: I tried this as well. But db2_exec() can't execute describe statement. Is there any way to execute DESCRIBE statements in php? Anyways, thanks for your help.